# Replace URL encoding with dashes in Slim with Twig?

Tags: php, url, twig, slim, slim-3

Is there a way with Slim to replace `%20` with dashes? I'm using this specifically for a search feature on my site and would like cleaner URLS by replacing the url encoding with dashes.

I couldn't find anything online stating that this was possible.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to replace the URL encoding? When passing data/variables to the template from PHP/Slim, or processing the data in the template file? If you are doing it before, you'll need to use PHP, if doing it in the template, then @mleko's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

In Twig there is [replace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) filter, you can use it.

```
{{ url|replace({"%20":"-"}) }}
```

Comment: I'm talking about in the actual browser URL, i would rather have dashes instead of %20 showing up.

Comment: @JoeScotto can you include screenshot and sample link? If you navigate to url with dashed, browser will display it that way.